# I want datepicker in that END date as current date and START date as 7 days previous to END date in Jquery r Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#end").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function () {
            var start = $('#start');
            var startDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 7);
            start.datepicker('option', 'minDate', startDate);
            start.datepicker('option', 'maxDate',$(this).datepicker('getDate'));
        }
    });
    $('#start').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"
    });
});
```

Above is my code and I want datepicker in that END date as current date and START date as 7 days previous to END date in Jquery r Bootstrap.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: the End date as current date and Start date is upto 7 days previous to current date is enable...the start date i picked among that 7 enabled days.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="start">
<input type="text" id="end">
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#end").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function () {
        var start = $('#start');
        var startDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 7);
        start.datepicker('option', 'minDate', startDate);
        start.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $(this).datepicker('getDate'));
    }
});
$('#start').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"
});
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kkuuzaoh/6/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: i want that previous 7 days are enabled..i choose any date from among 7 days...but in the above code if i choose To date the start date automatically as 7 days previous than end date...

Comment: what do you mean by same did you check the Fiddle Demo. its working .

Comment: the previous 7 days are enabled...i pick any day among 7 previous days...but in the above code what it will happens is if i choose end date as current date the start date as automatically 7 days previous to end date..but idnt want that

Comment: just try to read the code then you'll be able to find where is that modification. its just removing one line of coding.

Comment: in js fiddle its working....but i am tried to implement in eclipse its not working...in IE9 its not supported..

Comment: use proper Jquery version. see the Edited answer.

Comment: in End date only current date is enable remaining all dates are disabled...only current date is choose in end date remaining all dates are disabled....

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#end").val($.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/yy", new Date()));

        var endDateString = $('#end').val();
        var splitDate = endDateString.split("/");

        var endDate = new Date(splitDate[2], splitDate[1], splitDate[0]);
        var startDate = new Date();
        startDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() - 7);

        $("#start").val($.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/yy", startDate));
    });
```